# How can I optimize code for canActive angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

how can I optimize that code, my co-worker told me that this code returns true and false, I already did it but, he said it not correct and told that I need recheck!

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN');
    if (!this.token) {
      return this.router.navigate(['mypage']);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works in my case, but how can optimize that ?? is there any code lines need removed ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer short, it is what you expected?

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  this.token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN');
  return !!this.token || this.router.navigate(['mypage']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is looking good, but I can give a small suggestion

log him out if he is not `Authenticated`, before that clear his details from browser because he is not a valid user and we don't need his details(at least in my prospective).

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN');
    if (!this.token) {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.router.navigate(['/login']); // better to log him out
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I hope this helps.. :)

Comment: ok, but why you suggest to remove all entries from localstorage? It can holds usefull information

Comment: It always good to remove the user data, as soon as users logs out or the guard force it.

Comment: @Walter I don't think there is any useful information from a anonymous user.

Comment: @ganesh045 It depends on implementation, localstorage can hold info about selected language, currency, theme, etc. And the second case: you are logged and have some info in LS, then you logout (intentionally or session expired). In your solution you clear LS. When you login next time, your data will be vanished.

Comment: I agree with @WalterŁuszczyk - It depends on implementation. Normally I store tokens / roles in sessionStorage or localStorage which I do remove on user logout, and other information such as language is stored in cookies. So you should edit your answer as it really does depend on implementation.

Comment: @Dino I have already said that it is Just In my opinion. I am not suggested to clear the Cookies. As Walter said yes, It depends on the implementation and strategies of the Organisation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to return true or false, you can use this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN') !== null;
}
```

But if you need to save the JWT to token variable first, you can use this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN')
    return this.token !== null;
}
```

Comment: canActivate returns true or false because in the RoutingModule, or where you have the routes, you specifies that you must be authenticated by JWT, so you dont need to redirect there.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `route`, and `state` but you aren't using them. Let me explain how those two should be used.

Let's imagine this is one of your paths in `app.routing.ts`

```
{
 path: 'dashboard',
 component: DashboardComponent,
 canActivate: [AuthGuard],
 data: {role: 'merchant'}
}
```

You can see that we are passing a role too. You can pass any other relevant information here as well. Once you have that, it makes sense to use `route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` because it allows you to get that information you passed - and you do it like this:

```
route.data.role
```

Now let's talk about the `state`. Imagine that at some point your token expires or you lose access to the application for whatever reason and get logged out. Once you login back to the application, you would probably like to be taken where you left of. This is what `state` allows us to do because it has an access to current URL / route. Combining those things together, `route` and `state`, you could do something like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN');

    // If your route depends on role as well, you can get it with route.data.role
    if (!this.token) {
      this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }}); 
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Now when you get redirected to the login page you will have returnUrl in your router queryParams and you can easily use that to redirect to the last accessed page.

Answer (score 0):

> my co-worker told me that this code returns true and false

It seems your co-worker is not asking you to optimize the code, he seems to suggest that the method "canActivate" is expected to return true/false not expected to perform any side-effects and you are performing one by navigating to 'mypage'.

As per [angular definition](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) the "canActivate" method can return boolean or UrlTree. So you are not supposed to perform any side-effects inside the method. In your case you are navigating to mypage URL which is a side-effect. Instead create a UrlTree for mypage URL and return it and angular will take care of the navigation.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  this.token = localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN');
  if (!this.token) {
    return this.router.createUrlTree(['/mypage']);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```